# Audio plaback on laptop

Tags: c++, directx, audio-streaming

I wrote simple audio playback application on c++ via latest DirectX SDK. On PC it working fine (Windows xp, Vista, Windows 7), but when I execute application on laptop it produce only silence.

What differnce between audio on PC and laptop?

Comment: can post a source code of this? problem may be in source

Comment: I using RTAudio http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/index.html
for audio device access

Comment: Can you run some samples from rtaudio on both platforms. If it works, then it's a code problem; if not then it's a problem with your code

Comment: For test I am using RTAudio playback example, on pc ->ok, on laptop silence.

Comment: What API are you using? Legacy DirectSound or XAudio 2.7?

Comment: Note: 'the latest DirectX SDK' was June 2010 and is in fact deprecated. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx) as well as [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a hardware setup problem on your laptop.  Make sure the laptop has all the latest sound drivers, also check that it isn't muted, etc etc.

Comment: I can play any mp3 file on laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Run `DirectX Diagnostisc` for check problems with `DirectX`.

Go to the: *Start -> Run -> Type: dxdiag*

Answer (score -1):

Install the latest version of [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-us/aboutgfw/pages/directx.aspx) on the laptop.

Comment: The phrase "Installing DirectX" Is essentially meaningless on a modern version of Windows unless the OP is specifically getting an error about missing one of the side-by-side optional components like D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, or XAUDIO2_7.DLL, etc. See [Not So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Old skool! :D  This thread is 4.5 years old ... but yes ... your point is still fair ...